Lateral surface area of a twisted antiprism

The surface area of a right antiprism with regular $n$-gonal bases is equal to $2B + 2n\bigl(\frac{1}{2}sh\bigr) = 2B + shn$.  With a twisted antiprism, the top base is rotated by angle $\phi$ from its original position, which distorts the lateral faces.

I'm assuming that (despite the visual appearance) all of the new lateral faces are still identical to each other, which means that there is probably some formula for the new lateral surface area (the sum of all the triangular faces) based on $\phi$.  Is this correct?  If so, does anyone know this formula?  If so, a derivation of the formula would be a great bonus.

Are your figures taken from here ?

Hint : the sides remain triangles with same base b but not with same heigth h. You just have to compute h (as a function of $\phi$)  in order to apply formula area = $\tfrac12$ bh.

^Is the height the altitude outside of the triangle or perpendicular to the longest side inside the triangle?  I'm not quite sure what $h$ would be as a function of $\phi$.

The foot of the altitude is outside the triangle.

^I was asking whether your height referred to the altitude of the triangle or the line segment perpendicular to its longest side (which is inside the triangle).

Set up a coordinate system such that $z$-axis is the axis of the antiprism and vertex $A$ on the upper base has coordinates $(r,0,h)$ ($h$ is the height of the antiprism and $r$ is the radius of the base). The side $BC$ on the lower base corresponding to $A$ has then $z=0$ and $x=r\cos{\pi\over n}$.
Let's now rotate $A$ clockwise about the $z$-axis by and angle $\phi$, to $A'$. We have:
$$
A'=(r\cos\phi,-r\sin\phi,h)
$$
If $H$ is the projection of $A'$ on its base $BC$, we have then:
$$
H=\left(r\cos{\pi\over n},-r\sin\phi,0\right)
$$
and the height of triangle $A'BC$ is:
$$
h'=A'H=\sqrt{r^2\left(\cos\phi-\cos{\pi\over n}\right)^2+h^2}
$$
We can now compute the lateral surface of the twisted antiprism:
$$
\text{lateral area}=nsh',
$$
where $\displaystyle s=2r\sin{\pi\over n}$ is the side of the base.


Is r the inradius or circumradius?

Also I'm pissed this question was closed, it's a good question.

@John It's the circumradius. You can express it in terms of the side reversing the given formula.
